# Update closed case without reactivating it

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to update fields of an closed case without reactivating it?

How risky is it to edit data manually in the crm database?
We absolutly want to avoid multiple incident resolutions.

Edit:
We added custom attributes to case entity in our development environment. After import in production environment we  want to update these fields for all existing records.

Comment: Updating the data manually in Database is not supported by Microsoft. Can you explain the scenario, it will help to think about the possible solution.

Comment: With the SDK this isn't possible. Whatever you choose will be unsupported unless you reactivate the cases first.

Comment: @marvin you can always delete the incident resolution activity after re-activating/resolving the case again

Comment: @keerz the problem is that we need the correct 'createdon' date of incidentresolutions for reporting

Comment: @Marvin could you not copy the value of createdon to another field and report on that instead?

Comment: @glosrob but we want correct and clean data in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOB way or a supported way by which you can do this. The only option is to go ahead and do a DB update.
This sure will never be recommended or supported but if you know what you are doing then I would recommend to go ahead and do the update.

Note: Do not update the FilteredIncident views for your update query instead hit the base tables.

Comment: It only affects one int and one date field. Do you have any concerns filling them?

Comment: None at all, you should be fine with a DB update, but make sure the Date is converted to UTC format before the update.

Comment: Be careful of how this affects any support deals you have with MS before going ahead